# Paho mqtt connection lost

Tags: android, kotlin, mqtt, paho

I'm testing with paho mqtt client library with mosquitto.org broker service.

My connection code is at below.

```
buttonConnect.setOnClickListener{ view ->
    val topic = textViewTopic.text.toString()

    try {
        val msg = "now connecting... " + textViewUrl.text as String?
        Log.d(TAG, msg)
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        client.setCallback(this)
        client.connect()
        client.subscribe(topic, 1)

        buttonConnect.visibility = View.GONE
        buttonDisconnect.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } catch (ex: MqttException) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
        Toast.makeText(this, "$ex", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

But whenever connection complete, connection is lost as below logs.

> now connecting... tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883 connectComplete
>   reconnect:false, URI:tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883 connectionLost
>   connectComplete reconnect:true, URI:tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883
>   connectionLost connectComplete reconnect:true,
>   URI:tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883 connectionLost

Here is my full [activity code](https://github.com/badsaarow/EasylinkAndroid_Demo/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/io/fogcloud/demo/MqttActivity.kt).

What do I mistake?

Comment: try to connect with the different clientID if you're able to connect successfully then use random clientID from Paho's library

Comment: This ^ and I would suggest connecting in onResume and disconnecting in onPause

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  Even though tried another cliendID, result is same.  And removing disconnecting code at `onPause`  also did not change result.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this ?